# What should I call a class or variable which holds a collection?

Tags: naming, naming-conventions

Let's assume I have a class SuperPower, and that I want to put my super powers in a collection without exposing the implementation.

I try to avoid having collections as instance attributes. Instead I put it in a class to which I can move behavior otherwise left spread out in other classes.

I don't want to call it SuperPowerList, SuperPowerMap or similar, because it exposes the implementation.

I also kind of dislike SuperPowers, because it is too similar to the class it contains.

The same goes to variables of the type, "SuperPowers superPowers".

There must be a better way.

Comment: Mmm, you are probably right. I was hoping for something shorter though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about PowerPack or SuperPowerPack?

Comment: Pack is nice, way better than collection.

(Maybe other collection synonyms from the animal kingdom; parliament, shawl or hoard. ;-)

Comment: I have been using Pack now for almost two weeks and it is really good. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`SuperPowerCollection` sounds the best as I can see that in the Framework throughout. Variable naming can be anything you are comfortable with as it is not as important. I prefer `superPowers` which is more common with collection classes. To get more creative ideas, please post the question at [english stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Only if I wont be downvoted:

1. PowerPod
2. SuperForces
3. PowerGrid

are some of the fancy names I can think of :)

Answer (score 1):

Use either SuperPowerCollection or SuperPowers. 
Both are fine. 
I would like to add that I saw a case in code where an implementation
 got changed from List to Map, but the name of the variable remained objctsList -
this is quite horrible, so you are correct that a good practice will be to avoid providing implementation details in the variable name as they may change in time.

Comment: Actually, we tried using plural s. It really doesn't work. Not because of code issues, but because of human issues. It is very difficult to talk about the code. The difference in too small when spoken; "is this am instance SuperPowers class of instances of the class SuperPower"?

Comment: Then use SuperPowerCollection.